# Python - Picking DataFrame columns from all csv files in directory and merging into one

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read all `csv` files in a directory and merge a specific column in all files to a new `DataFrame`. Basically, the files are of the format:
`file_name.csv`

```
MainColumn A B C
```

Since the row order is constant in all the files, I am trying to extract the first column in `file1`. Then I want only column `B` from all files. So, the resultant `DataFrame` has to be:

```
MainColumn B B B B...
```

Where the `Bs` are the individual `B` columns from `file1, file2, etc.` This is my code so far:

```
data = pandas.read_csv('file_1.csv')

import glob

df2 = data[['MainColumn']]

for files in glob.glob("*.csv"):

    data1 = pandas.read_csv(files)
    df = data1[['ColumnB']]
    df2 = df2.append(df)
```

The resultant `df2` is not what is expected (it is of the form all rows from file1, then columnB is added after the rows from file1, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try concat: 
Specifying the concatenation axis is the key here, which I do not thing is available in df.append()

```
df2 = pd.concat([df2,df],axis=1)
```